# JSF: How to not show the element id in validation messages?

Tags: jsf

I have a simple JSF form with some validation on the input text.  Something like:

```
<h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{userHandler.user.firstName} required="true" />
<h:message for="firstName" />
```

Works fine.  Except that the error message looks like this:

"j_id786643870_20c27c0a:firstName: Validation Error: Value is required."

How do I tell JSF not to show the element id of the element and just show the text message?

That is, I only want it to say:

"Validation Error: Value is required."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either override it by specifying the `label` attribute:

```
<h:inputText label="First name" />
```

Or supply your own validation messages and specify it in `<message-bundle>` entry in `faces-config.xml`. Message keys are specified in JSF specification.

#### See also:

- [JSF validation - can this be simplified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034540/jsf-validation-can-this-be-simplified)
- [How to create new messages properties to add adequate error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772857/how-to-create-new-messages-properties-file-in-jsf-to-add-adeqate-error-messages)

Comment: Excellent!  label="First name" is exactly what I needed.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. There's also a `requiredMessage` attribute for the case you didn't knew that. Just go through the linked related questions.

Answer (score 1):

In JSF 1.2 you have the provision to display your own error message by using f:validator tag.

Not sure exactly converterMessage or errorMessage

Comment: For more info on this approach: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/javaserver-faces-jsf-validation-tutorial-error-handling-jsf-validator See "Custom validation components using Validator interface" at the bottom. Basically, this is how you code custom validators in Java that can be used anywhere, by implementing the Validator interface and setting validatorId on a f:validator tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.0, and you can actually set requiredMessage, converterMessage, and validatorMessage on the components themselves, when applicable. From the documentation:

[image: requiredMessage, converterMessage, and validatorMessage in the PrimeFaces 6.0 documentation]

Looks like BalusC is finally out of date. :P

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute

```
requiredMessage="Validation Error: Value is required."
```