# p:message change text of message

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I created a form with an  which is mapped to MyBean.beansField. I used the javax.validation.NotNull anotation to make sure it has to be entered. Everything works fine so far but the error message looks like:

beansField: can not be null.

Whatever I tried so far I couldn't remove the "beansField: " in front of the message.

Can anyone please tell me where this prefix comes from and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43093563/1599699

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to check if user entered data, you could alternatively use the `required` attribute of an input field in combination with the `requiredMessage` field, e.g. for an inputField:

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.beansField}" required="true" requiredMessage="Can not be null"/>
```

If you want to overwrite messages in general you have to edit or overwrite the messages.properties file:

1. Add this to your faces-config.xml
   inside the application element:

> ```
> <locale-config><default-locale>en</default-locale></locale-config>
>      <message-bundle>/resources/messages</message-bundle>
> ```

1. Put a file called
   messages_en.properties in your
   resources folder
2. Add messages you want to overwrite in this manner:

   javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED=Field ''{0}'' cannot be empty.

Comment: i solved it with the requiredMessage="#{msg.validation_notNull}". The javax.faces.component.... still does not work (but I still can solve it with the first tip). Thank you very much.

Comment: A detailed description for custom messages can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772857/how-to-create-new-messages-properties-file-in-jsf-to-add-adeqate-error-messages

Comment: @idefix You asked about `javax.validation.NotNull` :)

Comment: @Jigar: Yes, I know. Your solution was also helpfull (therefor) the +1. I know this solution does not solve the problem of the @NotNull anotation but the label ("beansField: ") disappeared and that was important for me. Still don't know where it comes from...

Answer (score 1):

add `ValidationMessages.properties` in your classpath (`WEB-INF/classes` or `resources` if using maven structue)

add

```
myapp.custommessage.notNull=your custom message
```

and annotate like

```
@NotNull(message="{myapp.custommessage.notNull}")
```

Comment: unfortunatly still results in "beansField: your custom message"

Comment: is there any error/warning related to `ValidationMessages.properties` file ? ?

Answer (score 1):

Hello this is a long list of messages that you rewrite

```
# ***** JSR 303 validation messages *****
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=El campo es obligatorio
javax.validation.constraints.Size.message=El campo admite de {min} a {max} caracteres
javax.validation.constraints.Min.message=El valor debe ser mayor o igual a {value}
javax.validation.constraints.Max.message=El valor debe ser menor o igual a {value}
javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.message=Solo caracteres válidos

# ==============================================================================
# Component Errors
# ==============================================================================
javax.faces.component.UIInput.CONVERSION=Se ha producido un error de conversión.
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED=El campo es obligatorio.
javax.faces.component.UIInput.UPDATE=Se ha producido un error al procesar la información enviada.
javax.faces.component.UISelectOne.INVALID=Error de validación: el valor no es válido
javax.faces.component.UISelectMany.INVALID=Error de validación: el valor no es válido

# ==============================================================================
# Converter Errors
# ==============================================================================
javax.faces.converter.BigDecimalConverter.DECIMAL=''{0}'' debe ser un número decimal positivo o negativo.
javax.faces.converter.BigDecimalConverter.DECIMAL_detail=''{0}'' debe ser un número decimal positivo o negativo formado por cero o más dígitos, que pueden incluir a continuación una coma decimal y una fracción.  Ejemplo: {1}
javax.faces.converter.BigIntegerConverter.BIGINTEGER=''{0}'' debe ser un número formado por uno o varios dígitos.
javax.faces.converter.BigIntegerConverter.BIGINTEGER_detail=''{0}'' debe ser un número formado por uno o varios dígitos. Ejemplo: {1}
javax.faces.converter.BooleanConverter.BOOLEAN=''{0}'' debe ser 'true' o 'false'.
javax.faces.converter.BooleanConverter.BOOLEAN_detail=''{0}'' debe ser 'true' o 'false'.  Cualquier valor diferente a ''true'', se evaluará como ''false''.
javax.faces.converter.ByteConverter.BYTE=''{0}'' debe ser un número entre -128 y 127.
javax.faces.converter.ByteConverter.BYTE_detail=''{0}'' debe ser un número entre -128 y 127.  Ejemplo: {1}
javax.faces.converter.CharacterConverter.CHARACTER=''{0}'' debe ser un carácter válido.
javax.faces.converter.CharacterConverter.CHARACTER_detail=''{0}'' debe ser un carácter ASCII válido.
javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.DATE=''{0}'' no se ha podido reconocer como fecha.
javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.DATE_detail=''{0}'' no se ha podido reconocer como fecha. Ejemplo: {1}
javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.TIME=''{0}'' no se ha podido reconocer como hora.
javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.TIME_detail=''{0}'' no se ha podido reconocer como hora. Ejemplo: {1}
javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.DATETIME=''{0}'' no se ha podido reconocer como fecha y hora.
javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.DATETIME_detail=''{0}'' no se ha podido reconocer como fecha y hora. Ejemplo: {1}
javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.PATTERN_TYPE=Debe especificarse el atributo ''pattern'' o ''type'' para convertir el valor ''{0}''.
javax.faces.converter.DoubleConverter.DOUBLE=''{0}'' debe ser un número formado por uno o varios dígitos.
javax.faces.converter.DoubleConverter.DOUBLE_detail=''{0}'' debe ser un número entre 4.9E-324 y 1.7976931348623157E308  Ejemplo: {1}
javax.faces.converter.EnumConverter.ENUM=''{0}'' debe poder convertirse en una enumeración.
javax.faces.converter.EnumConverter.ENUM_detail=''{0}'' debe poder convertirse en una enumeración a partir de la enumeración que contiene la constante ''{1}''.
javax.faces.converter.EnumConverter.ENUM_NO_CLASS=''{0}'' debe poder convertirse en una enumeración a partir de la enumeración, pero no se ha especificado ninguna clase de enumeración.
javax.faces.converter.EnumConverter.ENUM_NO_CLASS_detail=''{0}'' debe poder convertirse en una enumeración a partir de la enumeración, pero no se ha especificado ninguna clase de enumeración.
javax.faces.converter.FloatConverter.FLOAT=''{0}'' debe ser un número formado por uno o varios dígitos.
javax.faces.converter.FloatConverter.FLOAT_detail=''{0}'' debe ser un número entre 1.4E-45 y 3.4028235E38  Ejemplo: {1}
javax.faces.converter.IntegerConverter.INTEGER=''{0}'' debe ser un número formado por uno o varios dígitos.
javax.faces.converter.IntegerConverter.INTEGER_detail=''{0}'' debe ser un número entre -2147483648 y 2147483647. Ejemplo: {1}
javax.faces.converter.LongConverter.LONG=''{0}'' debe ser un número formado por uno o varios dígitos.
javax.faces.converter.LongConverter.LONG_detail=''{0}'' debe ser un número entre -9223372036854775808 y 9223372036854775807. Ejemplo: {1}
javax.faces.converter.NumberConverter.CURRENCY=''{0}'' no se ha podido reconocer como un valor de divisa.
javax.faces.converter.NumberConverter.CURRENCY_detail=''{0}'' no se ha podido reconocer como un valor de divisa. Ejemplo: {1}
javax.faces.converter.NumberConverter.PERCENT=''{0}'' no se ha podido reconocer como porcentaje.
javax.faces.converter.NumberConverter.PERCENT_detail=''{0}'' no se ha podido reconocer como porcentaje. Ejemplo: {1}
javax.faces.converter.NumberConverter.NUMBER=''{0}'' no es un número.
javax.faces.converter.NumberConverter.NUMBER_detail=''{0}'' no es un número. Ejemplo: {1}
javax.faces.converter.NumberConverter.PATTERN=''{0}'' no es un modelo de número.
javax.faces.converter.NumberConverter.PATTERN_detail=''{0}'' no es un modelo de número. Ejemplo: {1}
javax.faces.converter.ShortConverter.SHORT=''{0}'' debe ser un número formado por uno o varios dígitos.
javax.faces.converter.ShortConverter.SHORT_detail=''{0}'' debe ser un número entre -32768 y 32767. Ejemplo: {1}
javax.faces.converter.STRING=No se ha podido convertir ''{0}'' en una cadena.


# ==============================================================================
# Validator Errors
# ==============================================================================
javax.faces.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.MAXIMUM=Error de validación: el valor es mayor que el máximo permitido de "{0}"
javax.faces.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.MINIMUM=Error de validación: el valor es inferior que el mínimo permitido de ''{0}''
javax.faces.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.NOT_IN_RANGE=Error de validación: el atributo especificado no está entre los valores esperados: {0} y {1}.
javax.faces.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.TYPE=Error de validación: el valor no tiene el tipo correcto
javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM=Error de validación: el largo es mayor que el máximo permitido de ''{0}''
javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM=Error de validación: el largo es inferior que el mínimo permitido de ''{0}''
javax.faces.validator.LongRangeValidator.MAXIMUM=Error de validación: el valor es mayor que el máximo permitido de ''{0}''
javax.faces.validator.LongRangeValidator.MINIMUM=Error de validación: el valor es inferior que el mínimo permitido de ''{0}''
javax.faces.validator.LongRangeValidator.NOT_IN_RANGE=Error de validación: el atributo especificado no está entre los valores esperados: {0} y {1}.
javax.faces.validator.LongRangeValidator.TYPE=Error de validación: el valor no tiene el tipo correcto.
javax.faces.validator.NOT_IN_RANGE=Error de validación: el atributo especificado no está entre los valores esperados: {0} y {1}.
javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.PATTERN_NOT_SET=Debe definirse el modelo Regex.
javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.PATTERN_NOT_SET_detail=El modelo Regex debe estar definido como un valor no vacío.
javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.NOT_MATCHED=El modelo Regex no coincide
javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.NOT_MATCHED_detail=El modelo Regex ''{0}'' no coincide
javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.MATCH_EXCEPTION=Error en expresión regular
javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.MATCH_EXCEPTION_detail=Error en expresión regular, ''{0}''
javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE={0}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Global... Create a properties file (clientMessages.properties). Generally it's inside src/main/resources...
inside clientMessages.properties put,

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED=El campo ''{0}'' es obligatorio.
```

into .xhtml put:

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.beansField}" required="true" id="IdComponent"/>
```

or some primeFaces component

```
<p:selectOneRadio style="text-align:center" required="true" id="IdComponent"
            value="#{backingBean.value}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Mensual" itemValue="MENSUAL" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Única" itemValue="UNICO" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

For internationalization, If you have a maven project in faces-config.xml (into WEB-INF) put

```
<locale-config><default-locale>es</default-locale></locale-config>
     <message-bundle>clientMessages</message-bundle>
```

is not necessary put a complete path, because in maven projects when you compile, resources appears into (WEB-INF/classes/), and it is a sub folder from where is the faces-config.xml file ... this way working for me in all maven projects.